# Elasticsearch does not seem to be working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, globalize

I am using elasticsearch and globalize gems for full text searching and what I expect is that I can search for supplier name, localised description using czech/english analyzer.

Example: 
Supplier Name: "Bonami.cz"
Supplier Description_CZ: "Test description in czech."

It works when I search for "Bonami.cz", but it does not work (0 results) when I search for:

- "Bonami" (part of the word)
- "test" (description)

Based on documentation, the below methods should work, but apparently I have missed something. I verified the indexes and data is in ElasticSearch.

Also do I need to install somehow the czech/english analyzer before using it in the model?

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
require 'activerecord-import'

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.index_document  },  on: :create
    after_commit lambda { __elasticsearch__.update_document },  on: :update

    translates :description, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations

    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Globalize::MultipleFields

        mapping do
          indexes :id,             type: 'integer'
          indexes :name,           analyzer: 'czech'
          indexes :description_ma, analyzer: 'czech'
          indexes :description_cs, analyzer: 'czech'
          indexes :description_en, analyzer: 'english'
       end

       def as_indexed_json(options={})
          { id: id,
            name: name,
            description_ma: description_ma,
            description_cs: description_cs,
            description_en: description_en    
         }
       end

       def self.search(query)
         __elasticsearch__.search(
            {
             query: {
               multi_match: {
                 query: query,
                 fields: ['name^10', 'description_ma', 'description_cs', 'description_en']
               }
            }
           })
       end
end
```

Any idea, what is wrong? 
Thanks, Miroslav

**UPDATE 1**
I inspired with the solution from [Rails 4, elasticsearch-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392300/rails-4-elasticsearch-rails), but when I try to search now, for any word I always get zero results.

```
settings index: {
    number_of_shards: 1,
    analysis: {
      filter: {
        trigrams_filter: {
          type: 'ngram',
          min_gram: 2,
          max_gram: 10
        },
        content_filter: {
          type: 'ngram',
          min_gram: 4,
          max_gram: 20
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        index_trigrams_analyzer: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['lowercase', 'trigrams_filter']
        },
        search_trigrams_analyzer: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'whitespace',
          filter: ['lowercase']
        },
        english: {
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['standard', 'lowercase', 'content_filter']
        },
        czech: {
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['standard','lowercase','content_filter']
        }
      }
    }
    } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :name, index_analyzer: 'index_trigrams_analyzer', search_analyzer: 'search_trigrams_analyzer'
      indexes :description_en, index_analyzer: 'english', search_analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :description_ma, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
      indexes :description_cs, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
    end
end

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    { id: id,
      name: name,
      description_ma: description_ma,
      description_cs: description_cs,
      description_en: description_en    
    }
  end

   def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name^10', 'description_ma', 'description_cs', 'description_en']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          pre_tags: ['<em>'],
          post_tags: ['</em>'],
            fields: {
              name: {},
              description_ma: {},
              description_cs: {},
              description_en: {}
            }
        }
      }
    )
  end
```

This is what I see when I open elastic search URL for the given model:

```
{"suppliers":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"supplier":    
{"dynamic":"false","properties":{"description_cs":      
{"type":"string","analyzer":"czech"},"description_en": 
{"type":"string","analyzer":"english"},"description_ma":
{"type":"string","analyzer":"czech"},"name":
{"type":"string","index_analyzer":"index_trigrams_analyzer","search_analyzer":"search_trigrams_analyzer"}}}},"settings":{"index":
{"creation_date":"1445797508427","analysis":{"filter":   
{"trigrams_filter":
{"type":"ngram","min_gram":"2","max_gram":"10"},"content_filter":
{"type":"ngram","min_gram":"4","max_gram":"20"}},"analyzer":{"english":
{"filter":["standard","lowercase","content_filter"],"tokenizer":"standard"},"index_trigrams_analyzer":{"type":"custom","filter":["lowercase","trigrams_filter"],"tokenizer":"standard"},"search_trigrams_analyzer":{"type":"custom","filter":["lowercase"],"tokenizer":"whitespace"},"czech":{"filter":["standard","lowercase","content_filter"],"tokenizer":"standard"}}},"number_of_shards":"1","number_of_replicas":"1","version": 
{"created":"1060099"},"uuid":"wX9kf3OQSva24Iwk7sZ8AQ"}},"warmers":{}}}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Two steps were missing to have it working as expected => 
1. Re-import model data
2. Typo in names of description fields (instead of description_ma/en/cs, I had to use ma/cs/en_description.

```
     settings index: {
    number_of_shards: 1,
     analysis: {
      filter: {
        trigrams_filter: {
          type: 'ngram',
          min_gram: 2,
          max_gram: 10
        },
        content_filter: {
          type: 'ngram',
          min_gram: 4,
          max_gram: 20
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        index_trigrams_analyzer: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['lowercase', 'trigrams_filter']
        },
        search_trigrams_analyzer: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'whitespace',
          filter: ['lowercase']
        },
        english: {
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['standard', 'lowercase', 'content_filter']
        },
        czech: {
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: ['standard','lowercase','content_filter' ]
        }
      }
    }
    } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
         indexes :name, index_analyzer: 'index_trigrams_analyzer', search_analyzer: 'search_trigrams_analyzer'
      indexes :en_description, index_analyzer: 'english', search_analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :ma_description, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
      indexes :cs_description, index_analyzer: 'czech', search_analyzer: 'czech'
    end
   end

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    { id: id,
      name: name,
      ma_description: ma_description,
      cs_description: cs_description,
      en_description: en_description    
    }
  end

   def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name^10', 'ma_description', 'cs_description', 'en_description']
          }
        },
        highlight: {
          pre_tags: ['<em>'],
          post_tags: ['</em>'],
            fields: {
              name: {},
              ma_description: {},
              cs_description: {},
              en_description: {}
            }
        }
      }
    )
  end
```

Comment: You need to use the ngram analyzer.

Comment: Thanks @eliasah. I updated the settings in my model class, see the UPDATE 1 above, but now I get 0 results for any word I try to search for. Probably I am doing some dummy mistake :/.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to reimport the records. Now I see I can search also for partial strings. What still does not work is searching in description fields.

Comment: Because you still haven't defined it for the description fields. You'll need to set that explicitly in the mapping.

Comment: It is defined as description_en, description_cs, description_ma as the description field is using globalize gem. Also indexes are created for these fields and I double-checked the data is in ElasticSearch as well. Is there any other place or a different way how to define it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I never used gem or ruby in my life, but I can't find where you have defined the analyzers for your description fields.

Comment: Finally I figured out where the issue was and you guided me there very well. I had there a typo. Instead of "description_en", I had to use "en_description" (same for cs and ma locales). This solved the problem and now all works as expected. Once again thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to perform the search you are trying to do you'll to use the Ngram analyzer. (as discussed in the comments)